# Why does my object serialized to camel case?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I have an asp.net core 2 app.  I am serving objects to mobile apps.  My object is coming back with a camel case instead of a pascal case.  I have found some documentation and blog posts about why this is happening in asp.net core v1.  Unfortunately, the v1 fix doesn't seem to be working for me in v2.  How do I get my object to come back in pascal case?

TIA

```
[Route("PicturesByPictureId")]
[HttpGet]
public dynamic PictureByPictureId([FromQuery] string Token, [FromQuery] Int64 PictureId)
{
    var da = new DataAccess();
    var pic = da.PictureInfo(PictureId);
    var myPic = new
    {
        PictureId = pic.PictureId,
        PicFileUrl = pic.PicFileUrl,
///////////////more code.
    };
    return myPic;
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, this only seems to be happening on an HttpGet and when I send a single object, not a list.  Very strange...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this to your startup.cs file

```
services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(opt => {
                    opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
                })
```

Comment: Thanks Riyaz.  That was it.  I had gotten the impression that was a .net core 1.0 command.  I was wrong.  Thanks again.